# How to use a rate limiting class in a github repo?

Tags: python, rate-limiting

This is the repo. https://github.com/JamesGardiner/chwrapper

I have an API key, this repo looks like it has rate limiting built in (max 600 in 5 mins). But I'm not actually sure how to implement it in my code and allow it to wait then try again. I tried...

```py
count = 0
number_of_comps_to_ask_for = 10000
orgs_random_subset = random.sample(company_numbers_list, number_of_comps_to_ask_for)
search_client = chwrapper.Search(access_token=COMPANIES_HOUSE_API_KEY)
while count < number_of_comps_to_ask_for:
    for company_number in orgs_random_subset:
        count +=1
        response = search_client.filing_history(company_number)
        resp_json = response.json()
```

But i run into... `HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url`

It looks like the class `RateLimitAdapter` in `/chwrapper/services/base.py` handles it eloquently, but I don't know how to use it...